# Which expression is equal to $6 - 4(x + 3)$?

Tags: polynomials

Which of the following expressions is equal to 
$6 - 4 (x + 3)$?

A. $4x + 3$

B. $4x - 9$

C. $-4x + 9 $

D. $-4x - 6$

Comment: Well, which one is it?  If you don't know, ask us what you need to understand in order to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

$6-4(x+3)=6-(4\cdot x+4\cdot3)=6-(4x+12)=6-4x-12=-4x-6,$ so D is the answer.